# Building a wireless door opener

Tags: wireless, wifi

In my parents house, the door is 'unlockable' via a switch. As long as the button is pressed, the door is unlocked.

Since I often forget my keys, I thought to make a WLAN-Switch, which is controled by an app.

The software development part is not a problem, but I have absolutely no clue in electronics. A first thought is some kind of WLAN-module, which is attached on a wire to the existing door opener, and gives an impulse if activated. But

- what possible 'thing' exists out there?
- where is the best address for such electronic toys?

Comment: This sounds like a shopping question. Raspberry Pi would be a good fit for this application. Don't forget to secure your protocol against sniffing and man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a programmer, one of the simplest way is to use an USB relay and an network enabled mini computer, such as Beaglebone Black or Raspberri PI. That way you wont have to do any electronics at all.

USB relays are very common, for instance:

http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?category=9

http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/category/usb-actuators  (*)

http://sigma-shop.com/product/67/usb-relay-controller-one-channel-pcb.html

Just make sure you choose one matching or exceeding your door voltage/current requirements. Also, check what software is provided, being able to control it with proper API would certainly help :-)

One last thing: your door control wire is probably driving a big coil, you might have to protect the relay from voltage surges, with a TVS diode for instance.

(*) I do work for the company making theses.